# Angularjs: create a popover off a directive (no bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popover

I'd like the user tap a word to open popover.

The calling HTML is as follows:

```
<li>Type de sélection très appropriée aux plantes <span popover="Ce dit d’une plante qui se multiplie par fécondation croisée (le pollen vient d’une autre fleur que celle de l’ovule)">allogames</span></li>
```

The directive I have designed so far is as follows:

```
app.directive('popover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            "popover": "@"
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<a class="popoverTop" ng-click="openPopover(\'popoverTop\')">popover</a>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        }
    };
});
```

Q1) As you can see, I'd like the constant popover inside the a tag be replaced by the popover local scope variable.

Q2) How would you do to make a small popover in plain HTML/javascript appears right at the word? (no bootstrap usage)

---

[EDIT 1] I came up with the following, but I still have an issue with calling openPopover():

```
app.directive('popover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            "popover": "@",
            "def": "@"
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<a class="popoverTop" ng-click="openPopover(\'#popoverTop\', \'{{def}}\')">{{popover}}</a>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {}
    };
});
```

Though openPopover() is an existing controller method, when I tap on the link, ng-click is executed (I can see ng-click-active) but openPopover() is not invoked. I suspect an issue with the scope. How could I invoke a controller scope function from the directive?

Comment: You could use `ng-change` or `$scope.$watch` on your input variable to check for the right answer. (That's for Q2). Btw it is "Se dit d'une..." not "Ce dit d'une..." :)

Comment: You are not clear with what you want to do. I can make it but once you be clear with your question. tell me what should be done stepwise?

Comment: At that point, I now need to make the ng-click working, ie. fix the reason why openPopover() is not invoked. @micronyks (See EDIT 1 break which I tried to make clearer)

Comment: please provide fiddle. i'll update it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/R7HEV/8/  okay wait. update this and tell me what you  want more. click the yellow div. your method will work.

Comment: I modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stephanedeluca/R7HEV/9/. See I need to call the openPopover() which belongs to the controller. How to do that? @micronyks